# Import Bacpac file into Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, bacpac, azure-backup-vault

I have a bacpac file of db1 in my local. I want the bacpac file to import in database db2.
When I was trying to import the file using import option in SSMS (right click database and import data) there is no option to connect to the existing/already created db. I have an already created db where I only want to import the contents from the bacpac file into the db2.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Database doesn’t support, import BACPAC file into Existing database not possible only [New or Empty Database.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-import?view=sql-server-ver15)**

If you want to import the content file into Database 2, there are many ways you can get,

1. Export all your Database table view to Azure blob and import these files to your existing Azure SQL database with SSMS. Follow these steps

**Export Data to Blob Storage**

[image: ref 1]

[image: ref 2]

[image: ref 3]
[image: ref 4]

**Select source table and view -> Choose one or more table views and copy -> Next -> Execution successful -> close.**

> **Import data from blob storage to SQL Database**

You can reference this document:

https://www.sqlshack.com/connect-azure-storage-account-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/